# Windows Scheduler, process terminate event trigger fail because process started from external drive don't use disk letters

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, scheduled-tasks

I am searching for posts that tell people how to start a new task when a specific process got terminated, and finally found some old posts such as
"How to start a program when another one is stopped" and
"Scheduler trigger task when a process terminates" Both are helpful and teach us to setup new triggers in the scheduler to achieve the effect, but it seems no one had mentioned how to deal with the varying disk numbers in the process path.

I saw a new task successfully triggered when a process ended which started from the local drive "C:", but not from a external drive. I thought it would just be as simple as inputting the path starting with disk letter "D:...\process.exe" or "E:...\process.exe" in the XML code, but it turns out I need to use something different as provided by the Event Viewer like "\Device\HarddiskVolume##...\process.exe", and the "##" is a 2 digit number that changes everytime I connect the external drive to the laptop, so the process path in the scheduler needs to be updated too.

Is there any way to write a condition in the XML code that will regconize the process if the path contains the right keywords or to force the external drive to stick to a fixed letter or numbers?

What can we do so the XML code in scheduler can adapt the varying harddiskvolume ## in process path?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you trying to restart the same process? Is it the check that is failing, or the start that is? Perhaps a script is a better choice, especially if the target drive is changing. Also, I question why you're trying to run a process from an external drive. Is that really necessary?

Comment: No, not trying restart the same process. I am trying to run a new batch to reset some performance settings of my laptop after that program is terminated. It's the check that is failing. Please don't judge if it's necessary too early, because the program is so large (>100GB), my laptop doesn't have enough free space to store it for the moment, so I need to store it in a external SSD until the local disk have enough space.

Comment: It won't be a big problem if it can't be implemented with the scheduler, I just want to explore more possible solutions to this problem.